# How do i make my project open source if it contains other open source libraries?

Tags: open-source, licensing

I want to release a software project, essentially a web site, and put it up on GitHub.  I used several open source libraries (PHP) to create this web site. How do I provide proper attribution to the other libraries?

My goal is to invite other developers to contribute to the project, alter the code for their own use, run the altered web site from their own domain, and ideally improve the value and functionality for all. I do not want other developers to ever sell the code, nor sell their version of the code.  What license do I use for my project?

Comment: look at the creative common no commercial,copy left, license

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to do the following:

- upload your source code to an online public repository and add a
  license.txt file in your source that contains the license
  information.
- You can additional disclaimers/credit on your web site for the third-party scripts used within your source.

Regarding the license to select, I think it varies depending on the third-party script licenses..

For instance:
If the third-party script you use is released under GPL license, then you also have to release it under GPL, but I am not saying all licenses require this. Its just what a GPL license requires.

[GPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License) is the most common license to be found.

But you might wanna take a look at [Creative Commons Licenses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons_licenses) too.

EDIT:- I just found some thing that may help you choose your License see below link:
http://creativecommons.org/choose/

EDIT #2:- According to my research, and Creative Commons. [CC licenses are NOT recommended for Softwares](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Can_I_apply_a_Creative_Commons_license_to_software.3F).

---

### Helpful Links

http://opensource.org/faq

http://www.fsf.org/

http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html

http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html

http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-howto.html